# Android SQLite efficiently add lots of data if not exists

Tags: android, json, performance, sqlite, large-data

I have the scenario described below, and my question is:

- How can I make this more efficient?

  - Can I improve the table structures?
  - Can I improve the queries / data access and writing?

Currently It can parse roughly 100 objects per second.

**EDIT:** By adding InsertHelper on "case 1:", the speed went up for existing values, which mostly is the case. However, I can't find any resource on how to use it when you need "last_insert_rowid()"

Database structures:

```
data {
  id integer primary key autoincrement
  name text not null
  ...
}

reference {
  id integer (same id as in table1, not unique here tho)
  source text not null
  source_id text not null
}
```

The table 'reference' keeps references from a source and the id at the source to the id in my DB. Each entry in the 'data' table has at least one entry in the 'reference' table.

I have a JSON in stream where I parse and build one object at a time. The stream can be up to several MB with over 8000 objects. When the object is built, it will contain a reference.

For each object built I want to:

```
if(reference for this object does not exist){
  if(we find the object name in data)
    add to reference with the found id then break
  else
    add to data, get new id, add to reference then break
}
```

The code looks as (a bit pseudo-code to make it easier to read):

```
beginTransaction();
try {
  while(parsing next object is successful){
    if("SELECT 1 FROM reference WHERE source = ? and source_id = ?" == null){
      Object[] objects = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE name = ?"
      switch(objects.length){
        case 0:
          "INSERT INTO data (name) VALUES(?)"
          "INSERT INTO reference  (id, source, source_id) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), ?, ?)"
          break;
        case 1:
          "INSERT INTO reference  (id, source, source_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
  endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up the `SELECT` queries by creating indexes on the lookup fields, if you don't already have them.

All the functions that wrap SQL `INSERT` commands (`SQLiteDatabase.insert` and `InsertHelper.execute`) return the `rowid` of the inserted record.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter async mode for faster operations.
After you open your sqlite execute this query:

```
yourdb.execSQL("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
```

when you have finished inserting everything you wanted, flush the db with a simple close/reopen:

```
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase flush() {
    if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
        database.close();
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return database;
    }
    return database;
}
```

Hope this helps.